# Next song button and Previous song button in android audio player

Tags: android

i want to make an audio player which in android studio, i have done all the steps like play, pause, forward song, reverse song, but now my question is that to set two buttons, one for next song and one for previous song from memory list.. how to set it? help me anyone please.

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton playBtn;
    SeekBar positionBar;
    TextView elapsedTimelabel;
    TextView remainingTimeLabel;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int totalTime, next_song;
    String position_of_song;
    String elapsedTime;
    private boolean isMovingSeekBar = false;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arraylist=new ArrayList<>();
        getMusic();

        position_of_song = getIntent().getStringExtra("songID");
        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button);
        elapsedTimelabel = findViewById(R.id.totalTime);
        remainingTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.remaining_time);
        positionBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

        //MediaPlayer
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(position_of_song));
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);
        totalTime = mp.getDuration();

        //Seek Bar
        positionBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        positionBar.setMax(totalTime);
        positionBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (isMovingSeekBar) {
                }
                mp.seekTo(progress);
               // positionBar.setProgress(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        //thread update position Bar

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (mp != null) {
                    try {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.what = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int currentPosition = msg.what;
            //update position bar
            positionBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            //update labels
            elapsedTime = createTimeLabel(currentPosition);
            elapsedTimelabel.setText(elapsedTime);

            String remainingTime = createTimeLabel(totalTime - currentPosition);
            remainingTimeLabel.setText(remainingTime);
        }
    };


    //getMusic from memory
    public void getMusic(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(uri,null,null,null,null);

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int songTitle=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int songData=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

             do{
                 String currentTitle=cursor.getString(songTitle);
                 String currentArtist=cursor.getString(songArtist);
                 String currentData=cursor.getString(songData);
                 arraylist.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentArtist + "\n" + currentData);
                 Toast.makeText(this,currentData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public String createTimeLabel(int time) {

        String timeLabel = "";
        int min = time / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = time / 1000 % 60;
        timeLabel = min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timeLabel += "0";
        timeLabel += sec;

        return timeLabel;
    }

    private void pausePlaying() {
        positionBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            mp.pause();

        }
        else {
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
            mp.start();
        }

    }

    public void setPlayBtn(View view) {

        //playing
        if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.start();
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
            //pause
        } else {
            pausePlaying();
        }
    }


    public void reverseSong(View view) {
        positionBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() - 5000);
    }

    public void PreviousSong(View view) {

    }

    public void NextSong(View view) {


        }

    public void FarwardSong(View view) {
        positionBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() + 5000);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could have a global `flag` which stores the current position of `arraylist` Increment it in `next()` and decrement it in `previous` methods and assign this new file location to `mp`.

Comment: thanks for your response.. can you send me your idea in code.. ?